# WAMPserver DNS is Not Working for Virtual Hosts

Tags: networking, dns, wamp

I set up a virtual host for my laravel project, and while I can access the site via IP I cannot access it by domain name (it redirects me to WAMPserver's homepage). For reference I'll provide both relevant screenshots and code excerpts:

#### httpd-vhosts.conf File

```
#Dragon's Lair Laravel Project
<VirtualHost 127.27.18.28:80>
    ServerName dragonslair.test
    DocumentRoot "c:/laravelprojects/dragonslair/public"
    <Directory  "c:/laravelprojects/dragonslair/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

[image]

#### hosts File

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
192.168.10.10 dummyRegistration.test

127.27.18.28 dragonslair.test
::1 dragonslair.test
```

[image]

#### IP Address Resolves Properly

[image]

#### Domain Name Redirect

[image]

I would presumably create many virtual hosts in future, and don't want to start having to memorise their IP addresses, which is why I want to get the DNS working properly.

Comment: Do you have resolv for hostname dragonslair.test?

Comment: "resolv"? I am not sure what you're referring to @RomeoNinov.

Comment: what is the result of `nslookup  dragonslair.test`? If you have no output you should set it (possible in `hosts` file)

Comment: @RomeoNinov here's the output of `nslookup`: https://i.imgur.com/cxMD67L.png. Apparently, "dragonslair.test" is not set. I am not sure how to set it, I provided an example of my hosts file, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: In `hosts` file add line like: `127.27.18.28 dragonslair.test`

Comment: @RomeoNinov I already did that, it is among the screenshots I provided for my question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88148/discussion-between-tobi-alafin-and-romeo-ninov).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful if you still have a problem.
From **"hosts"** file remove this line of code   **::1 dragonslair.test**.
Because  **"::1"**  represents IPv6 of localhost and it is the same as the IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 and that could be the reason why it redirects you to WAMPserver's homepage.

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem

Comment: I am glad it helped.